# source development kit tutorials

Tags: source-engine

I'm looking to create a demo using the source development kit.
Because i want it to have a similar style to portal, but one I'm wondering can i get the portal 2 authoring tools without owning the game,
and two I'm finding it very difficult to find any form of tutorials for it, could anyone link me to some preferably PDF format or eBook i rather read them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to own at least 1 Source game before you are given access to the Source editing tools. I'm not quite sure what kind of demo you plan to make, or if that demo will require code changes or not, but I believe the Source SDK only provides you with Half-Life 2 mod tools, not Portal 2. You may be able to find more information on their website here: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Main_Page

You can however make very sophisticated maps using Valve's map editor called Hammer. And again, you will need to own any game you want to design maps for (otherwise how did yo plan to test them?). There are plenty of Hammer tutorials out there, although here is Valve's official level design page for Portal 2: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Category:Portal_2_Level_Design

Answer (score 0):

1. YouTube's got some good videos for beginners.  'World of Level Design' has some good ones on YouTube and on his own site. Type in 'SourceSDK' in YouTube's search bar and they'll pop up.  There's about 4 guys that have videos up on map making in SourceSDK/Hammer.
2. You need to buy the game to run the maps, but you don't need to buy the game to use the authoring tools.  That being said, just buy the game.
3. There's a Half-Life book-book, there's a downloadable Source Book (both on Amazon).

I recommend buying Left4Dead2 from Steam's website as it comes with SourceSDK/Hammer and you can watch those videos on YouTube.  It's not too hard to understand and get halfway decent at pretty quickly (1 day a week for 2 months and you'll be making some pretty spiffly looking maps).  You'll eventually get to the intermediate level and that's where there's problems, cuz for the life of me I cannot find a good source on how to transition from one map to the next and upload that to Steam so everyone can play your maps.